Proof that the definition of an n-element set obeys the axiom of extensionality
In Jech's set theory, after defining the unionset axiom, the author defines an n-element set. He first says that $X\cup Y := \bigcup\{X,Y\}$. Then, he makes the definitions $X\cup Y\cup Z := (X\cup Y)\cup Z$ and $X\cup Y\cup Z\cup A := ((X\cup Y)\cup Z)\cup A$ and so on. Up till now, it has only been proved that the empty set, singleton and doubleton sets exist. So, Jech defines a three-element set to be $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\} := \{a_1\}\cup\{a_2\}\cup\{a_3\}$. Further, he defines an $n-$element set in the following manner: $\{a_1,...,a_n\} := \{a_1\}\cup...\cup\{a_n\}$.
But nowhere in this section does the author show why such a definition is "good". Or, in other words, why such a definition obeys the axiom of extensionality. My question is, is it necessary to make this proof? If so, how do we write such a proof?

What does it mean for a definition to obey the axiom of extensionality?

@spaceisdarkgreen what I mean by that is that $\forall x\in {a_1,a_2,a_3}, x\in {a_1}\cup{a_2}\cup{a_3}$ and vice versa. Otherwise, such a definition isn't "obeying" the axiom of extensionality. My question is how can we that the definition is "obeying" the axiom of extensionality for any arbitrary n-sized set. I think it is crucial that this be shown. Otherwise, if we're just making definitions with no strings attached, I might as well say ${a_1,a_2,a_3} := {a_1}\cup{a_2}$. But of course, that's not a valid definition.

That has nothing to do with the axiom of extensionality and that's true because the thing on the left is defined as the thing on the right. We could very well say ${a_1,a_2,a_3}:={a_1}\cup{a_2},$ much as I could write a textbook starting with 'we say a number is prime if it is greater than 200"... it just would be unwise, misleading, and counterproductive to do so, not 'invalid' in any formal sense.

@spaceisdarkgreen Yeah that's where I have a disagreement. If we're, by definition, saying that ${a_1,a_2,a_3} = {a_1}\cup{a_2}\cup{a_3}$, we must show that the axiom of extension is obeyed. That is, we must show that $\forall x\in LHS, x\in RHS$ and vice versa. Otherwise, we're breaking the axiom of extension, which says that if two sets are equal then it must be true that $\forall x\in LHS, x\in RHS$ and vice versa. So, it's not the case that ${a_1,a_2,a_3} := {a_1}\cup{a_2}$ is not useful or unwise. It is incorrect by the axiom of extension

"Otherwise we're breaking the axiom of extension, which says..." No, the axiom of extensionality is the converse of that, saying that if sets have the same elements then they are equal. That if sets are equal then they have the same elements is just indiscernibility of identicals, i.e. two things that are equal have all the same properties... a basic logical principle governing equality having nothing in particuar to do with sets.

You can't tell me what the elements of ${a_1,a_2,a_3}$ are till you have a definition of what that expression means. ${a_1}\cup{a_2}\cup{a_3}$ is one way of defining it, provided you already have a definition of ${x}$ and $\cup$. If when you unwind those definitions you find you can prove that ${a_1}\cup{a_2}\cup{a_3}$  indeed actually has exactly $a_1,$ $a_2,$ and $a_3$ as elements (as the notation ${a_1,a_2,a_3}$ would seem to suggest), that just means the definition is working as expected.

@spaceisdarkgreen I see my mistake. The error I think is in me falsely believing that $a_1\in{a_1,a_2,a_3}$, $a_2\in{a_1,a_2,a_3}$ and $a_3\in{a_1,a_2,a_3}$ when there's no axiom to support this since the three-element set isn't yet defined. Would it suffice to show that ${a_1}\cup{a_2}\cup{a_3} = {x;|;x = a_1\lor x = a_2\lor x = 3}$ to show that this set has exactly $a_1,a_2,a_3$ as its elements? I have done this proof using the unionset axiom and the singleton and doubleton axioms.

Yes, that would be something to show (which identical to “showing the elements are exactly $a_1,$ $a_2,$ and $a_3$”). Note the reason we can’t just define it as the RHS is because that is written as an unbounded comprehension, so no way to know it’s a set. Expressing it as the union of singletons does the work of bounding it by a set.

@spaceisdarkgreen makes sense. Thanks a lot
